# Ordenar las columnas según la suma de las filas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo una dataframe `sim_scores` y me gustaría ordenarlo según la suma de las columnas. Puede haber 1 hasta n columnas:

```
                           elegant    sassy
_id
5fd5e643260828c7646000b2  0.100000 0.100000
5fd5e670260828c7646000ba  1.000000 0.045455
5fd5e772260828c7646000da  0.045455 1.000000
```

Intenté:

```
sim_scores = sorted(sim_scores, key=lambda x: sum(x[[features]], reverse=True)
```

Y obtengo:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Y también:

```
sim_scores.sum(axis=1).order(ascending=False).head(5)
```

Obtengo:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'order'
```

Ahora intento:

```
sim_scores = perfumes_scores.loc[(sum(perfumes_scores[[features]])).sort_values().index]
```

Comment: lo que tienes es el resultado de un groupby, no?

Answer (score 0):

Vamos a poner un caso base, tenemos el siguiente DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ordenar  = pd.DataFrame({"Nombre": ["Andrés", "Maria", "Marta", "Alberto"],
                         "N_casas":[1,4,3,0],
                         "N_coches":[0,1,1,2]})
```

**Aspecto del DataFrame**:

```
 Nombre N_casas N_coches
0   Andrés  1   0
1   Maria   4   1
2   Marta   3   1
3   Alberto 0   2
```

Podemos ordenarlo de la siguiente forma:

```
ordenar["suma"] = ordenar.sum(axis=1)
ordenar.sort_values(by="suma", ascending=False)
```

**Aspecto del Dataframe ordenado:**

```
Nombre  N_casas N_coches    suma
1   Maria   4   1   5
2   Marta   3   1   4
3   Alberto 0   2   2
0   Andrés  1   0   1
```

**Explicación**

- `ordenar["suma"] = ordenar.sum(axis=1)`: Creamos una nueva columna que será una suma del dataframe por columnas `(axis=1)`. Pandas solo sumará las columnas cuyo tipo de dato sea numérico, aquellas que no sean tipo númerico no las sumará, se puede ver los tipos de dato de un dataframe con `df.dtypes`.
- `ordenar.sort_values(by="suma", ascending=False)`: ordenamos los valores por el nombre de la columna creada anteriormente.

Se puede ver más sobre estos métodos en la documentación oficial de pandas:

- [pandas sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html)
- [pandas sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)